# Login Activity wont open when login link is click

Tags: android

I am trying to open `LoginActivity` screen from the `RegisterActivity` screen, but it does not go to `LoginActivity` and instead it goes to `HomeActivity`. My plan is to be able to have a register screen and if user has an account already, the user should be able to login by clicking on the link. For my `activity_register.xml`, I put the link android id as follows: `"android:id="@+id/login_link_textview"`.

**AndroidManifest.xml** (Updated 2/3/2020)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kumoapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"/>
</application>
```

**RegisterActivity.kt**

```
class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

    register_button_register.setOnClickListener {
        performRegister()

    }

    login_link_textview.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Try to show login activity")

        //launch login
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
...
```

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.kumoapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*

class LoginActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        initialize()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if(mUser != null)
        {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    private fun initialize() {
        val email = email_edittext_login.text.toString()
        val password = password_edittext_login.text.toString()

        login_button.setOnClickListener {
            if(email.isNullOrEmpty() || password.isNullOrEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter text in email/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Log.d("Login", "Attempt login with email/password: $email/***")

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this) {task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Log.d("LoginActivity", "Sign in success")
                        } else {
                            Log.e("LoginActivity", "Sign in failed", task.exception)
                            Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Authentication failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }

                    }
            }

        }

        back_to_register_textview.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Try to show login activity")

            //launch login
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, RegisterActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun updateUI() {
        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

Is this a token issue or did I not call LoginActivity properly? Here is the LogCat when I click on the link to open LoginActivity:

```
2020-02-02 17:26:55.130 8872-8872/? I/example.kumoap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-02-02 17:26:55.169 8872-8872/? W/example.kumoap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-02-02 17:26:56.513 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2020-02-02 17:26:56.567 8872-8903/com.example.kumoapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2020-02-02 17:26:56.671 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( fc6IZPVTjfUE3ScqffSaJg2Tpzb2 ).
2020-02-02 17:26:56.720 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-02-02 17:26:56.762 8872-8905/com.example.kumoapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2020-02-02 17:26:56.818 8872-8905/com.example.kumoapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
2020-02-02 17:26:56.827 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Collection enabled
2020-02-02 17:26:56.840 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.kumoapp, 1:742201828416:android:3ba68c024c12f1520beba5
2020-02-02 17:26:56.849 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 18202
2020-02-02 17:26:56.849 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-02-02 17:26:56.849 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.kumoapp
2020-02-02 17:26:56.849 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-02-02 17:26:56.889 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-02-02 17:26:56.993 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-02-02 17:26:57.059 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:26:57.073 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp W/example.kumoap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-02-02 17:26:57.074 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp W/example.kumoap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-02-02 17:26:57.276 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 7703380
2020-02-02 17:26:57.291 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2020-02-02 17:26:57.312 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2020-02-02 17:26:57.331 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_screen_class(_sc)=RegisterActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-6615119760841562676}]
2020-02-02 17:26:57.418 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe1d2e5a0, tid 8912
2020-02-02 17:26:57.422 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-02-02 17:26:57.446 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-02-02 17:26:57.447 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-02-02 17:26:57.447 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-02-02 17:26:57.447 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2020-02-02 17:26:57.447 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-02-02 17:26:57.447 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2020-02-02 17:26:57.456 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2020-02-02 17:26:57.456 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe1d048a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-02-02 17:26:57.490 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1d048a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe1d03900)
2020-02-02 17:26:57.497 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:26:57.498 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:26:57.545 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-02-02 17:26:57.546 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe1d2e8c0, tid 8912
2020-02-02 17:26:57.550 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-02-02 17:26:57.550 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2020-02-02 17:26:57.567 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1d048a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe1d03900)
2020-02-02 17:26:57.685 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-02-02 17:26:57.688 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2020-02-02 17:27:03.018 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2020-02-02 17:27:08.793 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp D/RegisterActivity: Try to show login activity
2020-02-02 17:27:08.815 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 11536
2020-02-02 17:27:08.827 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-02-02 17:27:08.829 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@27f7682
2020-02-02 17:27:08.848 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-02-02 17:27:08.848 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Activity paused, time: 7714915
2020-02-02 17:27:08.873 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=11536, ga_screen_class(_sc)=RegisterActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-6615119760841562676}]
2020-02-02 17:27:08.966 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:27:08.966 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 7715017
2020-02-02 17:27:09.032 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@59e5739
2020-02-02 17:27:09.036 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=RegisterActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=-6615119760841562676, ga_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-6615119760841562675}]
2020-02-02 17:27:09.043 8872-8872/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-02-02 17:27:09.118 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:27:09.119 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:27:09.119 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 208
2020-02-02 17:27:09.120 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:27:09.120 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Activity paused, time: 7715038
2020-02-02 17:27:09.124 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1d048a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe1d03900)
2020-02-02 17:27:09.138 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 7715196
2020-02-02 17:27:09.177 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=LoginActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=-6615119760841562675, ga_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-6615119760841562674}]
2020-02-02 17:27:09.284 8872-8912/com.example.kumoapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1d048a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe1d03900)
2020-02-02 17:27:09.437 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:27:09.437 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-02-02 17:27:09.438 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-02-02 17:27:09.440 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 7
2020-02-02 17:27:14.585 8872-8902/com.example.kumoapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Maybe there is something wrong with `login_activity.xml` ? I am still learning how to design layout, so my xml might not be the best you have seen.

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch"
    app:justifyContent="center"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignSelf="flex_start"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_edittext_login"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="90%"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edittext_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_edittext_login"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="90%"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/password_edittext_login"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="90%"
        android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/back_to_register_textview"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:text="Register an Account" />

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: please show your login activity code

Comment: I posted login activity code

Comment: try removing the extra launcher intent filters, i think they are causing a problem, there should only be one launcher with category main

Comment: I tried to changing to this `<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>` but no luck.

Comment: i think it s not complete error log.

Comment: ok I only showed when clicked on link, but I will show more details

Comment: I showed full log now

Comment: are you using emulator?

Comment: yes I am using emulator pie

Comment: make sure you have google account and google play service is updated on emulator

Answer (score 0):

Launcher is the one activity that starts your application, the rest should be default not Launcher like you did.

Comment: Ok I tried to change code to this : `<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"/>` and Register activity as is and still only goes to to HomeActivity when clicked. Is this code correct?

Comment: Maybe this is pointing to the wrong textview(probably from copy and paste) login_link_textview. You should also replace LAUNCHER with DEFAULT for Home and Login activities. Another thing is .MAIN should be .HOMEACTIVITY and .LOGINACTIVITY respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kumoapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"/>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"/>

</application>
```

In RegisterActivity.kt

```
login_link_textview.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(this@RegisterActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
```

Comment: Didnt work, I am starting to feel like, it didnt like my activity_login.xml

Comment: I posted my activity_login.xml, not sure if this is causing the issue.